# Dialog with EditText expands when selecting text

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to open a custom Dialog with an EditText.

The dialog is properly displayed at first, but shows a weird behaviour when the user selects text.

Normal state:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDbMM.jpg)

State when user selects Text:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go8o9.jpg)

My Java Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_description, null);

builder
        .setView(dialogView)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

        })
        .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

        });


Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

My Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/color4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Beschreibung bearbeiten"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/AlertDialogStyle"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/descr_edit_text"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Beschreibung hinzufügen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGrey3"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textAppearance="@style/myFont"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by User selects text?
Is it means, that after enterring anything, when user select that particular text, then the weird behaviour comes.

Comment: Probably it's a problem of your style `R.style.AlertDialogStyle` . Try omit that

Comment: @Shekhar: That's exactly what I mean. When the user tries to select the text inside the Edittext to copy it, the dialogs size increases.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman That's my R.style.AlertDialogStyle:

`<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

        <item name="android:background">@color/myColor4</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/myWhite</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myWhite</item>
</style>`